# How can I programmatically get the row at which a new UITableViewCell is created?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

Because my `UITableView` gets sorted by a date (not the current date), most of the time, when I tap a `UIButton` called: `Add` a new entry to a `NSMutableArray` gets added `[cellList addObject:managedObject]` which is the `UITableView`'s datasource, then the `UITableView` gets reloaded so that the new `UITableViewCell` is displayed. I want to get the `indexPath` of that new cell. But Like I said, since my `UITableView` gets sorted by a date, the `cellList`'s indexes doesn't always correspond to the  `UITableView`'s.

So how can I get the indexPath of the cell that was just created by reloading the table's data?

Any idees would be much appreciated!

Comment: If possible explain in detail it confusing I can't understand that how your code technically work!!

Comment: I rewrote my question, I cant post to much code, I don't have permission from my job.

Answer (score 0):

Look for documentation of NSIndexPath. It has properties like row & sections. I hope it should solve your needs.

Comment: I want to get the index path of the newly created cell. I dont have a indexPath yet so I cant call `row` or `section`.

Comment: You use this to add rows in table 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section.   


& use this to add data to the row


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   

here 'indexpath' can be used, to check for which cell the data is being filled.

Comment: That would be the perfect solution, but I'm reloading the uitableview after the user creates the cell. Meaning all UITableView's delegate methods re-run from the start.

Comment: I rewrote my question, I cant post to much code, I don't have permission from my job.